# Display Custom Post type in WooCommerce Product loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I've created a custom post type called "promo" with a meta field named "position." The admin can add any number of promos and assign a numeric value to the position field.

Now, when a user visits the WooCommerce shop page, I want the promos to appear between the products. For example, if a page has 12 products and the admin adds a promo with position 5, the promo should appear at position 5 within the product loop.

I've attempted to use the 'woocommerce_shop_loop' action, but it disrupts the pagination. Is there another solution to achieve this functionality without affecting pagination?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'wc_shop_loop', 100 );
```

With custom product loop as well

```
$args = array(
        'status' => 'publish',
        'category' => isset($term->slug) ? array( $term->slug ) : '',
        'limit' => $products_per_page,
        'page' => $paged,
        'paginate' => true,
        'return' => 'ids',
        'orderby' => $ordering['orderby'],
        'order' => $ordering['order'],
    );

    $products_ids = wc_get_products($args);
```

Comment: Create custom query loop and pagination for that query. wc_get_products as the name suggests expects products no other post types. Also since you will sort by some order i would recommend using same meta as products.